# char型変数に特定の文字が含まれているかを調べる関数は？

Tags: c

cの学習をしている中学生です。

配列のchar型変数に関連しての質問なのですが、"strcpy"にて入力した文字に対し、
例えば「"ANPAN"の中に"A"が含まれるのなら〜」的な関数はｃにはないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

文字列から文字列を探すのはstrstr
文字列から文字を探すのはstrchr

[Man page of STRSTR](https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/LDP_man-pages/man3/strstr.3.html)
[Man page of STRCHR](https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/LDP_man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html)